# How to make a list with all occurrences of the given atom doubled in Scheme

Tags: scheme

Here's an example about my question.

```
Example:
atom = a
list2 = (a (b c a (a d)))

output = (a a (b c a a (a a d)))
```

How can I do for this in scheme, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is not hard to program, once you have a clear idea of the general structure used to solve it. Because this looks like a homework, I'll let you fin the solution on your own, just fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (double-atoms lst atm)
  (cond ((null? lst)                            ; if the list is empty
         <???>)                                 ; then return the empty list
        ((not (pair? (car lst)))                ; else if the current element is an atom
         (if (equal? (car lst) atm)             ; if the current element == atm
             (<???> (double-atoms <???> atm))   ; then cons two copies of the current element
             (<???> (double-atoms <???> atm)))) ; else cons one copy of the current element
        (else                                   ; else the current element is a list
         (cons (double-atoms <???> atm)         ; then advance the recursion over the car
               (double-atoms <???> atm)))))     ; also advance the recursion over the cdr
```

It works as expected:

```
(double-atoms '(a (b c a (a d))) 'a)
=> '(a a (b c a a (a a d)))
```

Comment: It's very simple, two copies: `(cons (car lst) (cons (car lst) ... ))` . One copy: `(cons (car lst) ... )`

Comment: Here's the code, I still can make it work...would you please tell me what mistake I made :)
(define (double-atoms lst atm)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         ())
        ((not (pair? (car lst)))
         (if (equal? (car lst) atm)
             (cons (car lst) (cons (car lst) (double-atoms lst atm)))
             (cons (car lst)  (double-atoms lst atm))))
        (else
         (cons (double-atoms lst atm) 
               (double-atoms lst atm)))))

Comment: You have forgotten to add "cdr" and one "car" to (double-atoms lst atm). Whole code is: (define (double-atoms lst atm)
  (cond ((null? lst)
        ())
        ((not (pair? (car lst)))
         (if (equal? (car lst) atm)
             (cons (car lst) (cons (car lst) (double-atoms (cdr lst) atm)))
             (cons (car lst) (double-atoms (cdr lst) atm))))
        (else
         (cons (double-atoms (car lst) atm)
               (double-atoms (cdr lst) atm)))))

Comment: @林君翰 Ats fixed the errors in your code, and his solution above is correct. I hope you reached the solution first by yourself; please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful for you by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise the following recipe:

1. How do you solve this when you're dealing with a flat list, with no sublists?
2. Now, handle sublists using the same approach. Initially, you may want to assume sublists are flat, but eventually you'll need to deal with sublists of sublists.

You need to think about how to solve each step separately.

Answer (score -1):

```
(define (double-atoms l)
  (cond
    ; nothing to double in an empty list
    [(empty? l) '()]
    ; the first element is a list 
    ; => double atoms in it 
    [(pair? (first l))
     (cons (double-atoms (first l))
           (double-atoms (rest l)))]
    ; the first element is an atom, double it
    [else (cons (first l)
                (cons (first l)
                      (double-atoms (rest l))))]))
```

Comment: this answer is incorrect, not _all_ the atoms get doubled, only the one received as a parameter

Comment: True. I hope 林君翰 can modify the almost solution to a full solution.

Comment: mmm all right, maybe you should state that in the answer, otherwise people will think you misunderstood the question ;)